# How to call a function after a div is resized with the resizable() function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I was wondering after I resize a div that has the .resizable() feature on it, how do I make it call a function as soon as the user resizes the box and lets go of the mouse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable#events

You can use the stop event, which is triggered at the end of a resize() operation.